# Software to randomly combine graphic parts into a large graphic image

Tags: images, sprite, interpolation

First, from the other questions in this forum, I'm not sure if this is the right place for my question.
But I couldn't find a better one on StackExchange, so please apologize, and help me by indicating a right one, if my q is not appropriate here.
Thank you

I need to know if there is a software app that can take a set of graphic parts (something like "sprites" in old games), and combine them in random ways to generate a set of final images.

For example, feed it with a set of 10 eyes, 10 hairstyles, 10 faces, N noses, etc, etc, and ask it to randomly generate from that a set of X complete faces.

Comment: Not that I know the answer either way, but are you looking for 1980's style icons or right up there with Apple Memojis?

Comment: If you do a google search, there are various random face generators online which use AI to merge different samples from different parts of faces.

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer your question without some example of the result you expect. If you simply want to combine images as they are in predefined areas, you could use scripting in both Photoshop, Illustrator and InDesign. But if you expect the images to blend seamlessly together and scale, rotate  and position automatically, you need to look into some kind of experimental machine learning.